# Custom Timer Job NOT running when i run from UI but it perfectly run when I debugged

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-timer-job

I created custom timer job in my dev.environment. It is medium complex one that targets multiple lists and documents libraries and at last, it will apply item level permissions for a matching list items in a target document library.

The issue is, its working fine when I performed the debugging the code after attaching `owstimer.exe` and it successfully applied for the permissions.
But when I ran it from the central admin UI, by clicking the `RUN NOW` button, it didn't work. and also when I set it as 15 minutes interval, after 15 minutes, it did not run as well.
what may be the issue?

- I have restarted the sptimer services multiple times
- I have activated the web application scoped timer job feature through PowerShell multiple times.
- Did the iisreset

All these activities also in vain. When I clicked on RUN NOW, the permissions were NOT APPLIED and it didn't work.
Is there any other activity I need to perform in order to work it correctly?